# Why is the input parameter of Equals of type Object?

Tags: c#, equals

I've overridden *Equals(Object input)* thousands of times and never contemplated the matter deeper. Now, after a few drink, I started to think about it and it stroke me that I'm not entirely certain why it's so.

Equality operation is semantically speaking checking if two thingies are a copy of itself. Generally, it's done based on the pointer (reference value or whatever one might want to call it). On occasion, we'd like to define the equality as e.g. sum of some properties of instance *a* being the same as that of instance *b*, not necessarily being equal on any of them.

However, two objects of **different type** can't have the same reference, can they? And, even if two type have the same set of properties, called the same, typed the same, it's still apples and oranges, so the comparison will be either meaningless (at the very least) or darn damaging to the logic.

Is there any (and I mean **any at all**) occasion where the input to the operation of *Equals* might be of different type then the comparee **and still** make sense?

Comment: It's overridden from [`Object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx). You can alwayws implement the generic [IEqualityComparer<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`

Comment: 1) there is `IEquatable<T>` 2) What else would you use? The CLR doesn't support variance when oveeriding methods, and in any case you'd ne co-variance here, which violates LSP on parameters.

Comment: Regarding your question about two objects of different types not having the same reference: `class B : A`. `B b = new B();
  A a = (A) b;
    
  Console.WriteLine( a == b ); //will print true`

Comment: Well, an example is `Integer` can be equal to `ComplexNumber` with zero on imaginary part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumptions are wrong:

> Equality operation is semantically speaking checking if two thingies are a copy of itself. Generally, it's done based on the pointer (reference value or whatever one might want to call it).

That's **Reference equality** and it's checked by the function [Object.ReferenceEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx) (which is static and not overridable)

Object equality is different, and you can apply the rules you want to it. In case it wasn't like that, how would you check two *value types* (which cannot hold the same reference in C#) for equality?

Consider:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 5;
a.Equals(b); // what would this return? `a` and `b` are different objects
```

Now for the second part of your question, there are objects that, depending on your needs, may need to be considered equal being of different types. Consider:

```
public class Point2D {
  public int X, Y;
}

public class Point3D {
  public int X, Y, Z;

  public override bool Equals(object source) {
    var p2D = source as Point2D;
    if(p2D != null)
    {
      if(this.Z == 0 && p2D.X == this.X && p2D.Y == this.Y)
        return true;
      return false;
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

In this case:

```
var p2D = new Point2D(5,5);  // <-- let's pretend we have the right constructor  
var p3D = new Point3D(5,5,0);
object.Equals(p3D,p2D); // <-- returns true
object.ReferenceEquals(p3D, p2D); // <-- returns false
```

For performance (specially for value types), you may want to implement `IEquatable<T>` or `IEqualityComparer<T>` (or better yet, derive from `EqualityComparer<T>`), which allows for a direct comparison to a specific type (without having to box it to `object` before), but that's outside the scope of this answer.

Note that it's still recommended to override `Object.Equals` if you implement this interface so that the behaviour is matched between the two.

Comment: Ah, missed that (must be the drinks, hehe. Would you, please, mention the *IEquatable<T>* in your answer as well for +1? I'll accept it as soon SO will let me.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I don't see how `IEquatable` fits here. That's actually the assumption that an object will be checked against a specific type, and it's just a commodity interface (which allows for a bit better performance). I don't think anything related to `IEquatable` actually answers your question. But ok, I'll mention it :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to imply that your answer was flawed. You get the green check for the original version. However, I was wondering (and I can imagine that there's been others) about the type of comparison respecting the type. And since one of the comments mentioned it, I though it might be a good idea to remake your answer from good to great. And that's the +1 part.